# How to restart the Fedora + Cinnamon desktop from the command line?

Tags: cinnamon

In the Fedora+Cinnamon desktop, ALT+F2 opens a command window, and then entering a "r" causes the window session to be restarted, without terminating the login or any of the other running tasks.

What command can be executed, say from bash, to duplicate the effect of the "r" command?

Answer (score 1):

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.Cinnamon \
     /org/Cinnamon org.Cinnamon.Eval string:'global.reexec_self()'
```

For the gnome equivalent, see [How to restart Gnome...](https://askubuntu.com/a/672943) (Ubuntu).   Modified for this case (Fedora+Cinnamon) with some help from comments following [ALT+F2,"r"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/518069/352143)